# Quickly-editable config file, not visible to public visitors?

Tags: vuejs2

I am in the middle of working with, and getting a handle on Vuejs. I would like to code my app in a way that it has some configurable behaviors, so that I could play with parameter values, like you do when you edit your Sublime preferences, but without having to compile my app again. Ideally, I would want a situation where I could have my colleagues be able to fiddle with settings all day long, by editing a file over FTP maybe, or over some interface....

The only way I know how to do it now, is to place those settings in a separate file, but as the app runs in the client, that file would have to be fetched via another HTTP request, meaning it's a publicly readable file. Even though there isn't any sensitive information in such a configuration file, I still feel a little wonky about having it public like that, if it can be avoided in any way...

Can it be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can avoid this. One way or another your config file will be loaded into the vuejs application, therefore being visible to the end user (with some effort).

Even putting the file outside of the public folder wouldnt help you much, because then it is unavailable for HTTP to request the file. It would only be available to your compile process in this case.

So a possible solution could be to have some sort of HTTP request that requests `GET example.com/settings` and returns you a JSON object. Then you could have your app make a cookie like `config_key = H47DXHJK12` (or better a UUID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which would be the access key for a specific config object.

Your application must then request `GET example.com/settings` (which should send the `config_key` cookie), and your config object for this secret key will be returned. If the user clears his cookies, a new request will return an empty config.